# Scrollview added extra space at bottom of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

[image: 1]In my activity, scrollview added extra space at bottom of the page. I also tried finding on stackoverflow but nothing happen. I have tried everything but none works for me..Plz help

Here is my xml code -

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/basic_01"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_header"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

[image: 2]

Comment: Please share the Image basic_01.

Comment: provide your basic_01.png image file to solve your problem.

Comment: I added complete xml code and image.

Comment: any help about my problem..

Comment: What is your required UI, you can achieve this by LinearLayout easily.

Comment: I want to make only imageview scrolling, not spinner but scrollview takes lots of space at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"` in your `ScrollView` That's why it adding extra space at bottom of layout

Remove **`android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"`** from your **`ScrollView`**

Read more about [**`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)

Comment: this isn't work..In my activity, their is lots of space blank below the image (around a full activity space).

Comment: I added complete xml code and image. @Nilesh Rathod

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this flag in order to achieve what you want.
`android:fillViewport="true"`

Please post a screenshot so we can have clearer understanding of the layout.

Comment: He already added `android:fillViewport="true"` inside `ScrollView`

Comment: Please delete the this line of code from XML
`android:fillViewport="true"` from your ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:fillViewport="true" in scrollview.

Comment: As you can see, he's already have this exact line in his `ScrollView`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31110766)

Comment: he has added margin bottom thats why